# EF Core talking to postgres with citext datatype

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I need some assistance.
I'm running
.NET Core 3.1
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.2
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 3.1.2
against a postgres db
PostgreSQL 11.5

We moved from MSSQL to postgres, and previously this code was working:

```
_context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.EmailAddress == emailadress);
```

With that said, now the data is case sensitive and e.g. comparing "john.doe@mail.com" with "John.Doe@mail.com" stopped working.
One could change all to lower -strings, but as there is a lot of these kinds of comparisons, it would take some time to change this.
Then I found citext to the rescue, I thought.
I have altered the table/column and then there is the .net entity I'm a bit insecure of how fix.

I tried to add to the entity, based on this link:
https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/general.html?tabs=data-annotations

```
[Column(TypeName = "citext")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

but it didn't help.
I find this in the logs:
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[@__emailadress_0='?'], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
And I don't know if I should expect the CommandType='citext' here or not.

Do anyone have any input regarding this?
Thanks alot!

Comment: Is the spelling difference between "john.doe" and "Jo**h**an.Doe" intentional?

Comment: Sorry, autocomplete.. It should of course be the same name but capital letters and lower letters.

Comment: With SQL Server, I believe that behavior is governed by the collation rules for the database/table/column. I've never used postgres

Comment: @Johan I've just ran a quick minimal test and the above works correctly... I'd check again whether the column type really has been applied to your database. Otherwise try to create a minimal runnable program, and if you can repro it there please post that.

Comment: @ShayRojansky: Thanks for input and verifying. I created a minimal runnable program, and it did work. In the logs I still saw the CommandType='Text', and I guess I won't see the CommandType='citext' in that spot then.
I did find the issue though. Our data/tables existed in other schema than 'public', and the user which was used to connect didn't had default/preffered schema set. After this schema was set, it worked. Weird, but it solved my issue. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Great to hear it worked out! Note that CommandType has nothing to do with the parameter type (text/citext). CommandType Text just means the *command* contains a regular SQL statement (as opposed to StoredProcedure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user used to connect to the Postgres database didn't have default schema set. The data/tables used, didn't exist in the default schema set for the database. After the preferred/default schema was set on the user used, to connect to the database, the citext comparison started to work.

```
    ALTER ROLE myUser IN DATABASE myDatabase SET search_path TO mySchema;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that a new migration with that type change is applied to your database.

Another thing to consider is the collation used by your database. What I think is that just after you have migrated from MSSQL to Postgre the collation has not been preserved.

Comment: Hi @Tony! Thanks for responding. Well, I edited the table myself in the db, changing the column type to citext from text. In the .net modell/entity I added the prefix on the column as you can see. It doesn't work anyway..